# How do I load a library?

Tags: javascript

How do I load a library?

I feel very foolish for asking such a supposedly mundane thing, but I couldn't find the answer on [Ecma-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/) or [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/JavaScript).

Solution must work with `d8` (V8), `jjs` (Nashorn), `js` (SpiderMonkey), `rhino` (Rhino), `seed` (JavaScriptCore).

Comment: JavaScript has no native features for loading libraries. How you do it is host environment specific (but many support [AMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_module_definition)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ('undefined' === typeof(require)) {
    if ('function' === typeof(load)) {
        require = load;
    } else if ('object' === typeof(imports)) {
        require = function(library_name) {
            eval(imports.gi.Gio.file_new_for_path(
                library_name).read().get_contents());
        }
    } else {
        throw('require not implemented');
    }
}

require('./some_library.js');
console.log(some_library.some_function(some_parameters));
```